# Document library item permissions

Tags: 2007, document-library, permissions, explorer-view

I have a document library containing a lot of personal information. Originally only admins could see the library but now it has been decided that users need to see their own information. Admins have Full Control and users have Read. The default view shows only documents where the user's name appears in a certain field. So Default View, Name="[Me]" so they can only see their own files. This works fine but it doesn't stop users from opening the library in Explorer view. How can I stop them doing this?

Any suggestions?

Note: I do not have access to Central Administration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the code from the following [blog post](http://salaudeen.blogspot.co.uk/2012/09/hide-new-button-in-sharepoint-document.html) and some hints from this [one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32622/SharePoint-Customization-Tricks-Part-1?).

Below is the code I finally used, it will disable Explorer View for everyone but admins can then create their own Explorer view if required.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("hideToolbarItem()");
    function hideToolbarItem() 
    {   
        var doc = document.getElementsByTagName('ie:menuitem');      
        for (var i = 0; i < doc.length; i++)   
        {
            itm = doc[i];
            if (itm.id.match('OpenInExplorer')!=null) 
            {
                itm.hidden=true;          
            }   
        }  
    } 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a few views on how to achieve this:

- [How to Hide “Open in Windows Explorer” option from List or Document Library in SharePoint 2007](http://sharepointpolice.com/blog/2010/04/25/how-to-hide-%E2%80%9Copen-in-windows-explorer%E2%80%9D-option-from-list-or-document-library-in-sharepoint-2007/)
- [How can I manage the “Open with Explorer” button based on user permissions?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/32044/how-can-i-manage-the-open-with-explorer-button-based-on-user-permissions)

Comment: For the first link you've sent me I can't find the file they are referring to I get to Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\12 and the only folder I have is BIN.